# Can India nationality apply for an APEC card?

Tags: indian-citizens, india, apec, abtc

Can a Singapore permanent residence with Indian Nationality apply for an APEC card?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you can't.  Only APEC passport holders and permanent residents of Hong Kong are eligible:

> To be eligible to apply for an ABTC **you must hold a valid passport from an APEC economy** (or be a permanent resident of the Hong Kong Special Administrative Region [...]

https://www.apec.org/Groups/Committee-on-Trade-and-Investment/Business-Mobility-Group/ABTC